# Azure BlobBaseClient.OpenReadAsync() leads to: System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (...)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, .net-5

I'm reading data as stream from Azure Blob and creating a File from the stream than an I'm getting *System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (3692 of 3696).*

I used DownloadToAsync() till now and everything worked fine, but I had to switch it with OpenReadAsync() because I need to deserialize the data from the blob stream  directly he in some of my other endpoints).

simple code here:

```
using var blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();
return File(blobStream, "application/octet-stream", "file-name");
```

Comment: Can you please try  upgrade the azure blob storage version   or even try with downgrading the version .Or  If you came up with  any idea or suggestion  please provide your feedback here  >> [https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: I tried upgrading azure.storage.blobs to 12.9.1 - didn't help. Downgrading will be quite complex as I have to make changes on several of our microservices - going to pass on that for now. It looks to be a bug or so(created an issue) - when using OpenReadAsync() it adds 4 bytes on top of the stream, which causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Client-Side Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption?tabs=dotnet) for your blobs?

I also ran into this issue as well when passing the stream returned by OpenReadAsync to File().  blob.OpenReadAsync() returns the stream for the encrypted file.  The amount of data actually read out of the stream was actually 11 bytes less than the stream claimed (.Length) which screws up setting Content-Length in File().  The change in length is presumably due to the decryption happening as the stream is read.

```
using (var blobStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())
{
   // blobStream.Length = 36832
   using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\test.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
   {
       await blobStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
   }
}

var fs2 = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\test.zip", FileMode.Open);
// f2.Length = 36821
```

Passing f2 instead of blobClient.OpenReadAsync() fixes File(). Writing the blob stream to a temporary location first before passing to File() doesn't seem ideal, though I'm not sure how else you'd get the true file length.

**UPDATE**

My initial answer was only trying to illustrate that the length issue is due to the encryption.  If you need to stream the blob back to the browser and you are dealing with large files, then I would suggest not using FileResult.  Instead try this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task DownloadFile()
    {         
            // these 2 lines depend on the type of file your downloading to your user. Example assumes it's a zip       
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = $"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"whatever.zip\"";
            
            // ... get your blob from azure

            using var encryptedBlobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();
            // you might want to experiment with different buffer sizes
            var buffer = new byte[4096];                
            var count = 0;                
            while ((count = encryptedBlobStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                await Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, count);                    
            }                
    }
```

This worked for me. It should allow you stream out the large file with only allocating a buffer size of memory. The browser downloaded the file and it was unencrypted.  The HTTP response headers (as seen from Chrome) have not Content-Length but doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Yes, I use client-side-encryption. As I'm working with large data your suggestion wouldn't work for me. Thanks anyway.